# Python how to get reference to class in static method

Tags: python, static-methods

How can I get a reference to the class in a static method?

I have following code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        ...
    @staticmethod
    def load_from_file(file):
        args = load_args_from_file(file)
        return A(*args)
class B(A):
    ...

b = B.load_from_file("file.txt")
```

But I want to B.load_from_file return object of type B, not A.
I know if load_from_file wouldn't be a static method I could do

```
def load_from_file(self, file):
        args = load_args_from_file(file)
        return type(self)__init__(*args)
```

Comment: A staticmethod has no access to the class *by definition*. Why don't you want something else, say a classmethod?

Comment: Yes, thanks, Never heard about class method and it is exactly I need.

Comment: @JaraM I suggest searching also for _factory method pattern_ (more general term) especially if you want to compare with languages other than `python`.

Comment: @Daweo: To be clear, that design pattern is designed to cover gaps in other languages; in Python, stick to `classmethod`s.

Comment: @Daweo still good to know something like that exists :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `classmethod`s are *for*; they're like `staticmethod` in that they don't rely on instance info, but they *do* provide info about the *class* it was invoked on by providing it implicitly as the first argument. Just change your alternate constructor to:

```
@classmethod                          # class, not static method
def load_from_file(cls, file):        # Receives reference to class it was invoked on
    args = load_args_from_file(file)
    return cls(*args)                 # Use reference to class to construct the result
```

When `B.load_from_file` is invoked, `cls` will be `B`, even though the method is defined on `A`, ensuring you construct the correct class.

In general, any time you find yourself writing alternate constructors like this, you *always* want a `classmethod` to enable inheritance properly.